# Ubuntu 18.04 Сворачивается игра при переключении раскладки

Tags: ubuntu, layout, steam

ОС: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Раскладка ru/en
Установлен Gnome Tweaks для переключения раскладки на Alt+Shift. Также по умолчанию раскладка изменяется по комбинации win+space.

Есть steam-игры Counter-Strike 1.6 и Dota 2.

При переключении раскладки (неважно каким образом - alt+shift или win+space) в игре Counter-Strike 1.6 происходит сворачивание игры. При переключении раскладки в Dota 2 сворачивания игры не происходит.

В чем может быть проблема?

*** все еще актуально

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам поможет отключение индикации переключения раскладки, если таковая имеется.
Также проблема может быть в настройках самой Counter-Strike 1.6. Попробуйте сменить комбинацию смены раскладки и посмотрите: будет ли игра сворачиваться.
Возможно проблема в ОС, попробуйте обновить Ubuntu до последней версии (если у вас стоит устаревшая). Надеюсь, что хоть чем-то смог вам помочь.

Comment: Я уже написал, что это с разными комбинациями.
Что значит отключение индикации, не понимаю. Как тогда видеть, какая сейчас раскладка.
По поводу версии, я указал какая у меня.

Comment: @pav1uxa Сейчас почитал другие форумы. Насколько выяснилось, это старый баг с раскладной (над ним разрабы уже 2 года сидят). Возможно поможет смена среды рабочего стола, но это  не точно